# Получаю ошибки в NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Почему у меня ошибка при запуске app.js в PuTTY? :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 node.js:486
        throw new Error('Implement me. Unknown stream file type!');
              ^
Error: Implement me. Unknown stream file type!
    at createWritableStdioStream (node.js:486:15)
    at process.stderr (node.js:517:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/p/parliaub/pwnz22.ru/example/node_modules/debug/node.js:37:32)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/p/parliaub/pwnz22.ru/example/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:11:13)
```

Comment: нет файла server.js ?

Comment: блин, перепутал лог ошбики) в общем основная ошибка на картинке указано, кто нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Под юзером пытаемся использовать порт меньше 1024, или порт уже используется

Comment: поправил, в основном получаю данную ошибку `throw new Error('Implement me. Unknown stream file type!');`

Comment: @zb' если бы порт был занят там было бы написано EADDRINUSE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Написано же -listen EPERM. Вы пытаетесь получить доступ к порту на который у вас нет прав.

Comment: После смены порта появилась ошибка `listen EACCES`, но на сервере я использовал порт который предлагал саппорт сервера. Странно то что с портом 3000 можно выводить "Hello" сообщение но запустить чат на основе NodeJS+socket.io, никак не получается.

Comment: [Ошибки Linux](http://ru.manpages.org/errno/3)