# Не удаётся запустить скрипт на хостинге Таймвеб

Tags: node.js

Помогите плиз

Код:

```
var http = require('http');

//create a server object:
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.write('Hello World!'); //write a response to the client
res.end(); //end the response
}).listen(3000);
```

Ошибка:

```
cq73023@vh58:~/public_html/services/node$ node test.js 
events.js:183 
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event 
^

Error: listen EPERM 0.0.0.0:3000 
at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11) 
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20) 
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1338:19) 
at listenInCluster (net.js:1396:12) 
at Server.listen (net.js:1480:7) 
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/c/cq73023/public_html/services/node/test.js:7:4) 
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30) 
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10) 
at Module.load (module.js:565:32) 
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
```

Comment: У вас виртуальный хостинг или vds?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получаю ошибки в NodeJS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485481/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-nodejs)